# Why is .simpleString() method of spark schema truncating my output?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a very long schema that I want to return as string

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

...

SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(new SparkConf().setAppName("YourApp").setMaster("local")).getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> parquetData = spark.read().parquet("/Users/demo/test.parquet");

String schemaString = parquetData.schema().simpleString();
```

The problem is the resulting schema looks like (see "10 more fields"):

```
struct<test:struct<countryConfidence:struct<value:double>,... 10 more fields> etc etc>
```

Using

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there some configuration option I can use that means `.simpleString` does not truncate? I've tried `parquetData.schema().toDDL()`, but it doesn't print the format I need.

Comment: It looks like `simpleString()` is the wrong method to use here. If I look at the [documentation for it](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType.html#simpleString--), it says, "Readable string representation for the type," which probably means that it's for humans to read when debugging, testing things in a REPL, etc., rather than from producing a machine-readable (XML?) schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a deeper look inside `simpleString` method, you can see that Spark uses a `truncatedString`, where `SQLConf.get.maxToStringFields` is passed as third argument.

The definition of this configuration is described as:

```scala
val MAX_TO_STRING_FIELDS = buildConf("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields")
  .doc("Maximum number of fields of sequence-like entries can be converted to strings " +
    "in debug output. Any elements beyond the limit will be dropped and replaced by a" +
    """ "... N more fields" placeholder.""")
  .version("3.0.0")
  .intConf
  .createWithDefault(25)
```

`Solution`

Tweaking `spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields` to a higher number than 25, like 50 (arbitrary, but should be determined by your use case), for example:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("Spark app name")
  .master("local[*]")
  .config("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", 50)
  .getOrCreate();
```

Good luck!